# Open/SaveFileDialog select CustomPlaces folder by default

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

We are using the `CustomPlaces` property of the Open/SaveFileDialog to show the users a variety of configured standard folders that they could use.

What we would like now is to have the `InitialDirectory` property point to the created `CustomPlaces` "folder". Has anyone been able to do this?

I have read through the MSDN articles for the [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class (and the subsequence OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog), the [InitialDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) property, the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumerator and [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) list, but all to no avail.
I have also tried to set the `InitialDirectory` property to the application's name incase that was the magic.

Code used for the OpenFileDialog (the directories are demos atm):

```
using (OpenFileDialog tempDiag = new OpenFileDialog())
{
  tempDiag.CustomPlaces.Add(@"C:\Temp\");
  tempDiag.CustomPlaces.Add(@"C:\Program Files\");
  tempDiag.ShowDialog();
}
```

Desired default selection when calling the `tempDiag.ShowDialog();`:

[image: CustomPlaces selected on opening]

I am aware that one could entirely customize the XOpenDialog via the methods described in this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy) article, but I feel that that would be a bit extreme just for the default selection at this point.

Comment: there is no documented API to change the selection in the left tree.